# Why forms using WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking does not open on Visual Studio 17.5.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have updated my visual studio to version 17.5.0, and, after the update, when I try to open a form that uses the library WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking I see the following error poping up on Visual Studio:

[image]

However, if I switch back to visual studio version 17.3.6, the form opens normally. What I thought is that after the update of visual studio to version 17.5.0, it updates the dotnet SDK to version 7.0.0 (but my application is targeting donet 6). I don't know exactly what is the root cause of it. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: The root cause is that you use a library that was written for .net2.  Backwards compatibility is nice, but that does stop somewhere.  Use [the source](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite), migrate the projects and build the library for .net6-windows

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant. But why would it stop working just by updating the visual studio (and not changing anything on code)?

Comment: You got a design-time exception, the designer built into VS was updated to also support .net7

Comment: Humm I see, let me know if I understood your suggestion correctly. You suggested migrating the WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking project to dotnet  6, right? Once I migrate, compile and build the lib project. Where should I put the lib output?

Comment: @Samuel You can either link to it directly (reference the dll from your project) or add the folder with the new nuget to the package search path. Of course, you could also (additionally) provide a pull request on the repo so that eventually the library gets an update.

Comment: Got it. Would you like to post your comments as the answer of this question?

Comment: @PMF You could post your comments as the answer of this question. I need to do some more research for my answer, it seems to me that the problem is with Microsoft.Win32.Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possibilies to consume a dll or nuget package that you need to build yourself (from a fork of a github repo, for instance).

- Of course the preferred solution would be to create a pull request on the original repo, so a new release could be made. Of course, this doesn't work if the library is no longer maintained or the PR is otherwise not accepted.
- You can add a directory (e.g. "c:\packages") to the nuget search path of your consuming project by adding a corresponding entry in that project's nuget.config file like this:

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="LocalSource" value="c:\packages" />
</packageSources>
```

- You can directly link to the dll from the consuming project (I'd try to avoid this for newer projects, because it's inflexible)
- Upload the new project to your local nuget server (preferred if you have one anyway and/or are working in a team).

In either case, make sure that your new package has a different version from the original .nuget package, to avoid conflicts. If two different .nuget packages have the same version, the restore behavior will be undefined.